# error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) Google Calendar

Tags: java, android

I'm follow the guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#insert-calendar)
for adding event on Google Calendar but it don't add event into calendar and i have error:

error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

and

```
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

is not used, Why?

code main:

```
    long calID = 3;
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis() + 11*60*1000);
values.put(Events.DTEND, beginTime.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
// 
// ... do something with event ID
//
//
```

manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.inscal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.inscal.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add this permission in your Androidmainfest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And here is a code to implement Calendar event using Intent :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What is meant by 'accept' if you use the intent it directly opens the Calender event

Comment: if I use intent it opens the event and asks me if I want to accept it or delete it. I have to add many events on the calendar and accept all are uncomfortable.

Comment: As your are also implementing same thing can i known the difference and what u are implementing....

Comment: With "intent" i have this. [link](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/5914/screenshot2013030308374.png)
I need add the event automatically without "cancel" or "done".